# How long are mongodb realms retained on a device by default?

Tags: realm, realm-mobile-platform, realm-js, realm-database, mongodb-realm

How long are mongodb realms retained on a device running the application by default (Sync/Normal) Does it matter if its a normal or synced realm? If so whats the default retention by the device for both?

Answer (score 1):

Both synchronized and local Realms are kept on the device indefinitely (that is, until the user deletes the app or clears its local data). Synchronized Realms are "normal" Realms, the only thing special about them is that in the background, there's a process that pushes and pulls data from the server. But the database is completely identical to the non-synchronized database.

Comment: I can confirm this after speaking with one of the realm guys, thanks for your answer! It's basically just another file on the device. You can use the api to clear them as well.